# Smallest Java SVG Engine

Tags: java, svg, batik

What is the smallest Java SVG engine (least/smallest jars) that actually works?  If your answer is Batik, what is the minimal dep. graph for getting this to work in a simple Java application?

I've looked at the dependency graph on the Batik site, but it looks like a typical Apache mess.  Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[SVG Salamander](http://svgsalamander.java.net/?six_charachters_limit) claims to be much smaller thank Batik. It's hard not to believe them. Whether it's as full featured, I can't say, but a co-worker said good things about it.

Comment: `SVG Salamander` is a small dependency, but has rendering issues with some SVG features, namely CSS.  Latest release spits this to console with an Optimized SVG from Inkscape:

 `Mar 17, 2016 4:24:08 PM com.kitfox.svg.xml.StyleSheet parseSheet
WARNING: CSS parser not implemented yet`.

Which in my testing, can result in missing color information or other rendering oddities, depending on the features used.  In the testing I'm performing, it's single-color shapes, and they appear black when rendered using SVG Salamander.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/), the jar file is 45k only (it provides an `SVGGraphics2D` implementation that is not only small but also fast - see [this blog post](http://www.object-refinery.com/blog/blog-20140423.html) for details).

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading as `JFreeSVG` creates SVGs, it doesn't render them, per their forum: "Rendering SVG within a Java application is a different problem, and not one that JFreeSVG attempts to solve."

http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=117136

Comment: Sure, it depends what the original poster meant by "SVG engine" - a generator or a renderer?  Batik does both, JFreeSVG does generation only.